# Building a CNC with external drivers - RAMPS needed?

Tags: arduino, cnc

Well, I'm upgrading a closed-source CNC machine with Arduino (and GRBL), but I'm confused if I really need the RAMPS board. I want to drive the motors with external drivers. I have a RAMPS 1.4 board here, a Arduino Mega, external stepper drivers and whatnot. Until now, no issue here.

I tried to use the Arduino Mega without RAMPS, plugging the external drivers directly on the Arduino and it worked just like it should. Then I used RAMPS and to no surprise it also worked like it should.

[image: A RAMPS board]

*(A RAMPS board)*

[image: External Stepper Driver]

*(External Stepper Driver)*

Now there lies my question: Is the RAMPS board just there to provide more "ease-to-use" and/or "plug-n-play-drivers" or does it more? I noticed that there are some capacitors and stuff on the RAMPS board, are they still useful if I use external drivers or won't I need them?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This question is off topic here because it is about the *usage* of a product for which you provide no technical detail having of purpose of which you are literally unaware (as that is your question).  To be on-topic here, posts need to state a singular, specific, *engineering design* question *supported by the necessary information*.

Comment: Sorry that I was unclear, @ChrisStratton, but I found nothing Googling for it and I thought someone should ask this question at least once "on the internet", so I posted it here. I'm sure it won't help only me, it's not a too specific question.

Comment: This is the wrong place "on the Internet".  This place is strictly for *electronic design* questions *only*.  What you have is an unfamiliar-user question, that belongs on a user *forum* where people discuss building CNC machines from *modular* components.

Comment: @Fusseldieb Welcome to EE stackexhange - People here tend to be salty and spend more time arguing about how adequate the question is, rather than actually contributing to answer :). Get used to it.

Comment: It's not that the question is inadequate in general, it is that it is fundamentally outside the mission of this site.  Stackexchange is unique, there is a whole rest of  the Internet for freeform discussion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RAMPS is a board with a pre-made interface. Here is a picture of what it has:
[image]

As far as I know, it is mostly used for 3D printer control. There is a rather large community around it, so if something is not working, you can rely on support from others.
Other than that, it really does not do anything special.

Regarding capacitors - they are part of the stepper driver circuit. If you use a driver of your own, it probably already has all the components necessary on board.

So yes, you are right, the board is for ease of use and "plug-and-play", with all typical interfaces necessary to drive a 3D printer, collected on one PCB.